# Recursive breadth first traversal in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, recursion, tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to discover why my traversal isn't working.  I believe I've isolated the problem to the point in code where it says "directory contains" and then what was passed to the function.  The function gets passed an array containing all of the new file paths to echo but for some reason it is only receiving the first one.  Am I passing the array incorrectly or could it be something else?

```
#!/bin/bash

traverse(){
  directory=$1
  for x in ${directory[@]}; do
    echo "directory contains: " ${directory[@]}
    temp=(`ls $x`)
    new_temp=( )
    for y in ${temp[@]}; do
      echo $x/$y
      new_temp=(${new_temp[@]} $x/$y)
    done
  done

  ((depth--))

  if [ $depth -gt 0 ]; then
    traverse $new_temp
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass arrays as arguments. You can only pass strings. You'll have to expand
the array to a list of its contents first. I've taken the liberty of making `depth`
local to your function, rather than what I assume is a global variable.

```
traverse(){
  local depth=$1
  shift
  # Create a new array consisting of all the arguments.
  # Get into the habit of quoting anything that
  # might contain a space
  for x in "$@"; do
    echo "directory contains: $@"
    new_temp=()
    for y in "$x"/*; do
      echo "$x/$y"
      new_temp+=( "$x/$y" )
    done
  done

  (( depth-- ))
  if (( depth > 0 )); then
    traverse $depth "${new_temp[@]}"
  fi
}

$ dir=( a b c d )
$ init_depth=3
$ traverse $init_depth "${dir[@]}"
```